# Define BootstrapValidator callback in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, bootstrapvalidator

According to [this](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/callback/) documentation BootstrapValidator supports custom validation callbacks.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha"
            data-bv-callback="true"
            data-bv-callback-message="Wrong answer"
            data-bv-callback-callback="checkCaptcha" />

function checkCaptcha(value, validator){}
```

But how can I define the same callback in CoffeeScript? I tried to define global function without succcess:

```
@checkCaptcha = (value, validator) ->
```

In case of using *@checkCaptcha* it's necessary to setup

```
data-bv-callback-callback="document.checkCaptcha" />
```

which is a little bit ugly. Is there some scope object, can be used for my purposes?

UPD.

```
$ ->
    f = (x) ->
        console.log(x)

f(123) //error
window.f(123) //error
document.f(123) //works well


$ ->
    @f = (x) ->
        console.log(x)

f(123) //error
window.f(123) //error
document.f(123) //works well
```

Comment: Try it without the `@`, then your function should be on the `window` object. This is not best practice though, but will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: If you want to define `window.f`, why not do that?

Answer (score 1):

Why not include and then use this cool namespace function [recommended by Coffeescript's creator himself](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/FAQ#unsupported-features):

```
namespace = (target, name, block) ->
  [target, name, block] = [(exports ? window), arguments...] if arguments.length < 3
  top    = target
  target = target[item] ?= {} for item in name.split '.'
  block target, top
```

...then you can just make yourself a namespace:

```
namespace 'Captcha', (exports)->
  exports.checkCaptcha = (value, validator) ->
```

and use:

```
data-bv-callback-callback="Captcha.checkCaptcha"
```